# Cannot understand how following sample code works

Tags: python-3.x, operators

`['f', 't'][bool('spam')]`

this gives result ,

`'t'`

But I cannot understand how this sample of code works?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21732123/convert-true-false-value-read-from-file-to-boolean and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840803/how-to-convert-false-to-0-and-true-to-1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Any non-empty string is evaluated to `True` in a boolean context, so we have

```py
['f', 't'][True]
```

The `bool` type is a subtype of `int`, with `True` and `False` basically being `1` and `0` respectively, so we end up with

```py
['f', 't'][1]
```

Which should make it clear why the output is `'t'`.

Similarly,

```py
['f', 't'][bool('spam')]
```

will output `'f'`.